# sending and image through goRPC

Tags: image, go, rpc, grpc

I want to send an image through rpc using the golang packet [valyala goRPC](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala) and I'm having some problems to receive the image type in the server.

This is my client code, who takes an .jpg image, decodes it and send it through rpc:

```
c := &gorpc.Client{
  // TCP address of the server.
   Addr: "127.0.0.1:12345",
}
c.Start()
reader, err := os.Open("barranco.jpg")
if err != nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer reader.Close()

img, _, err := image.Decode(reader)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


fmt.Print("Pulsa intro para enviar.\n")
bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadBytes('\n') 

gorpc.RegisterType(img)

resp, err := c.Call(img)
```

So in this code, I take an image called barranco.jpg, I decode it but before sending it to the server I register the type on the client.
My problem is, how can I register that type in the server? I always get the same fail in the server because I can't register that image type /:

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `image.Image` is an interface so you can't register it, it's too abstract. Underlaying implementations for jpeg however are either `image.Gray` or `image.YCbCr`, both concrete structs, you may type assert `img.(Gray)` to decide which. Try to register both `image.Gray` and `image.YCbCr`, assert which you have have and then send as concrete type.